# Stored Procedures Using Entity Framework for large inserts/updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I'm using Entity Framework to call a stored procedure. I have a scenario where this one procedure, all said and done, is called 3000 times and then for each one of those 3000 stored procedure calls, another stored procedure would be called anywhere from 1 to 100 times. It's taking about 20min all together. I'd like to cut that time in half. Is there anything I can do to optimize this?

Basically this is what's happening:

```
foreach (var parentObject in parents) //parents.count = 3000
{
   int id = _efContext.prInsertParent(parentObject.Name, parentObject.values, etc..);

   // Have to get SCOPE_IDENTITY() id to be able to add children
   foreach (var child in parentObject.Children) //children count up to 100 items
   {
       _efContext.prInsertChild(id, etc..othervalues);
   }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would rethink the architecture. 3000 stored procedure calls shouldn't be acceptable, and far less so when exponentially impacted by the additional 100 calls. So, worst case scenario, 300,000 calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a user-defined table to allow me to pass in multiple rows to do a bulk insert. Cut my time in half. I'm satisfied. :)

Basically followed this:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-insert-into-table-using-userdefined-table-type1

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I'd rethink your architecture.

1. Think of leveraging the power of your DB. Insert data into a staging table, then process it after that. Use a temporary GUID for parent-child relationship, for example.
2. Use some bulk copy mechanism, such as EntityFramework.BulkInsert available from NuGet, or even the standard SqlBulkCopy type that is part of the .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting data... The data has to get in one way or another.. 
i would try setting these to false.. prior to insert.. and see what you get.

```
  Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
  Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Wouldn't these configurations only apply to actual entities(POCO)? I'm just calling stored procs

Comment: You are right..   I would want to know where the most time is spent on the insert.  Assuming that you have to drive this over a network?   Is it transient time..  You could try to slam all the data into some sort of byte array and compress it and send that as a parm.. Then have the SP on the other side unravel it and do all the inserts there.. (assuming your DB sp can deal with those things..

Comment: I am not sure if you want the maintain the structure and the ID's post insert in your app though